# LibreOffice converts files from RTF to PDF to plain RTF text

Tags: java, pdf, rtf, libreoffice, jodconverter

I'm using **jodconverter**:

```
import org.jodconverter.core.document.DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry;
import org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeException;
import org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeUtils;
import org.jodconverter.local.JodConverter;
import org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManager;
```

That uses **libreoffice** to convert RTF files to PDF.
The thing is that it converts the majority of them correctly. I'll detail all the proceses of the conversion:

First I encode string rtf file to base64 because the original    applicaction invokes another one where the actual conversion happens:

```
    // Encoding the string to Base64
    String base64Document = new String(DatatypeConverter
                            .printBase64Binary(stDocument.getBytes()));
```

Then the invoked application converts the string to PDF:

```
try {
    officeManager = 
        LocalOfficeManager.builder()
        .officeHome(LIBRE_OFFICE_PATH)
        .install().build();

officeManager
    .start();

byte[] inputBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(fileInBase64);
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes);

ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JodConverter
    .convert(input)
    .to(output)
    .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.PDF)
    .execute();

pdfEnBase64 = 
    Base64.getEncoder()
    .encodeToString(output.toByteArray());

} catch (OfficeException oe) {
```

Then the caller application decodes it back to normal string:

```
// Decode base64
byte[] byteDocument = Base64
        .decodeBase64(stDocumentPdf
        .getBytes((java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

Then it downloads it in the browser:

```
                var uintBytes = new Uint8Array(fileContent);
                var blob = new Blob([uintBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
```

But some files convert to PDF with core rtf content - this is the actual converted file when I open it in PDF Reader, as if jodconverter copied and pasted the content of the RTF file or something, I can't figure it out:

[image]

As seen, Adobe PDF Reader considers it a ligit PDF file, that's why it opens it without any problem.

There is no error whatsoever. A helping hand would be nice.

### EDIT:

I just ran tests, there are many rtf documents that convert correctly. I looked at the ones that convert badly like in the question and saw that removing the document header solves the problem. I'm investigating to see why the header is causing the conversion to fail.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for text based information! Please edit your question

Comment: Well it isn't "done" as we still have a picture of a text file. Yes, .rtf is a specialized text format. Also your code doesn't quite match the description as you're not creating a pdf, you're creating a base64-encoded pdf

Comment: I will add more code, one sec.

Comment: @g00se I am not creating a pdf base64-encoded, it just that I convert to base 64 first because there is an application that invokes another one where it converts to pdf and returns the result. But I decode it back to normal text before the conversion as shown in the edit

Comment: It might be useful to post the base64 *input* too, if that's what you've got. The problem being your last-posted rtf is corrupt according to Libre

Comment: The last posted rtf is the converted result file by libre. I had a screenshot first. This is what pdf reader shows when I open the file with it

Comment: PDF Reader considers it a ligit PDF file, that's why it opens it without any problem but shows like the last script, which is the actual pdf

Comment: I may publish the screenshot of the pdf reader back?

Comment: *The last posted rtf is the converted result file by libre* This is getting confusing. I thought the *input* was rtf..?

Comment: @g00se Maybe now it's a bit clearer?

Comment: The input is RTF the result is pdf . . .

Comment: @g00se please look at the screenshot, which the actual converted file. It's a PDF file opened in Adobe PDF Reader.

Comment: I'm not interested in the PDF file I'm interested in the input. Please post the base64 version of it

Comment: The thing is that it's confidential data, I can't post it, and its pretty long one . . .

Comment: You've already posted *something* haven't you?

Comment: Well the first part which has no data, only font data, the other information is realted with client personal data

Comment: You need to post something which can reproduce the problem

Comment: I'll edit the confidential part and post

Comment: @GingerHead could you use a random, short RTF document for testing, as a minimal, viable example? if the error is in some conversion done, that would also rule out potential formatting issues in the confidential data, as well as making it reproducible bu SO contributors

Comment: @JoSSte I just ran tests, there are many rtf documents that convert correctly. I looked at the ones that convert badly like in the question and saw that removing the document header solves the problem. I'm investigating to see why the header is causing the conversion to fail.

Comment: @GingerHead Good to hear that you have progress